# Most efficient way to grep files in directories for deletion using bash/aliases

Tags: bash, grep, debian, spam

I have a Debian Virtual Private Server that hosts several virtual domains and users. It was configured so in order to host multiple domains and have multiple email addresses (users or accounts) under each domain name.

I do get spam quiet often, and did not have the time to look on `SpamAssasin` on how to filter certain emails based on matched string in the email's body.

Instead, the following function was added to the `.bash_aliases` and it was aliased for quick access use

```
my_new_del() {
  echo "0:  $1"
  for d in /home/vmail/*/ ; do
      # echo "1:  $d"
      for f in "$d"info/*/*.some.file.pattern*;do
          grep -i -H -l -s "$1" "$f" | while read -r line ; do
              echo "rm -rf $line"
              rm -rf $line
          done
          # echo "2:  $f"
      done
  done
}
alias my_del=my_new_del
```

Then I use the above alias:

```
my_del 'some string' &
```

The script does the job, but it is really slow, and seem inefficient. It loops through each subdirectory in the vmail directory (each subdirectory represents a domain name). Then it loops through the files in each subdirectory and then greps for the string - and deletes it if it gets a match.

Can this be done in a more efficient manner?

Comment: Edit your Q to say how many files are under the `/home/vmail` dir. It looks like you're reprocessing all files each time to run this, so if you can figure out a way to hide/move files that are clean and then only scan new files, that should speed up your process significantly. Good luck.

Comment: You appear to be invoking `grep` once for each presumably tiny file. This is much slower than if you let `grep` search multiple files at the same time.

Comment: @thatotherguy how can grep search multiple files? I assumed that if you run `grep 'string' *` it will still loop through the files in the directory, no?

Comment: @shellter number of files in each directory is completely random. How am I gonna know how many emails were received? I am processing all the files each time because each time it checks for a different/new string. I do not want to move the files around because the webmail client uses a certain file/folder hierarchy when displaying and processing the emails/files.

Comment: The point of asking is that the approach may be different if you have a thousand, a million, or a billion files. You wouldn't know exactly how many, but you would know within a few orders of magnitude.

Comment: Right. I have a bunch of files, some folder can have 1-2 files, another 3000. For that reason I broke it down into the first FOR loop that then calls the GREP. I faced an issue where GREP was reaching a limit of number of files it can work with and then just erroring out.

Comment: That's simply a bug in your script where you were calling grep the wrong way for the problem you were trying to solve.

Comment: wrt `I assumed that if you run grep 'string' * it will still loop through the files in the directory` - there is a vast difference in performance between `grep string *` and `for f in *; do grep string "$f"; done`. In the former you are only asking the shell to spawn the grep process (a time consuming task) once total while in the latter the shell is spawning it once **per file**. Again, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't provide any sample input/output so this is untested but it sounds like this is what you're trying to do:

```
my_new_del() {
    find /home/vmail -type f -name '*.some.file.pattern*' -exec grep -i -H -l -s "$1" {} + |
    xargs rm -f {}
}
```

I'm assuming your file names don't contain any white space since your existing script relies on that assumption.

Comment: What would the sample input output be? There are files, and the contents of the files match or do not match the `'some string'`. It is in the question itself. How is your answer any more efficient than what I currently have? My solution also work.

Comment: Input: The result of running `ls` on a directory containing 3 files + the result of running `cat` on each of those files to show that one or 2 do contain the target string and the other(s) don't. Output: the result of `ls` again showing that the expected files were removed. How is it more efficient? It'll be orders of magnitude more efficient as it's avoiding nested loops (including an innermost `while read`) and extraneous commands. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219) for some of the issues with shell loops.

Comment: `My solution also work.` - you asked `Can this be done in a more efficient manner?` and I showed you how. It's also more robust as your script contains basic shell bugs like no`IFS=` on the while read and unquoted variables - given some file names you could find yourself removing complete different files than the ones you wanted to.

Comment: Ed, thanks, I am not a bash wiz, and do want to know how is it more efficient? Thanks. No disrespect..

Comment: It's more efficient by not having nested loops. Why not create a test directory with many files, some that contain the target string and some that don't, and run `time` on your function and my function to see the difference?

Comment: I used to have something very similar to what you had - and at some instances GREP would error out due to exceeding the number of files it could work with

Comment: Your original script was slow primarily because it did 2 forks per file. This version only does ~0.001 forks per file. It should be dramatically much faster.

Comment: No, that's not a concern with this solution. It uses xargs and `find -exec +` to avoid it.

Comment: Works like a charm. I did call the aliased functions with the `time` command to time the execution. The original script ran in: 
`real    3m19.912s
user    0m16.260s
sys     0m25.832s`

Where the newly modified one ran in 
`real    0m6.008s
user    0m4.588s
sys     0m0.684s`. A great improvement. Thanks